# Changing the numbers in two different intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Currently I am using the following formula:

```
=1 + (FLOOR((ROW()-2);5) / 5) + (FLOOR((ROW()-2);5) / 5) * 6
```

to change the numbers by 7 in different intervals and everything is working fine and you can see column A.  But numbers should change by 15 for every 5th change and again the rest 4 changes should change by 7 (see in column B):

[image].

Is it possible to build a formula like that?

Comment: I believe the formula `=1 + (FLOOR((ROW()-2);5) / 5) + (FLOOR((ROW()-2);5) / 5) * 6` was designed already to use in two different intervals, since as it stands it would be the same as `=1 + (FLOOR((ROW()-2);5) / 5) * 7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your formula a bit to be shorter and a little safer:

```
=1+(INT((ROWS($C$1:C2)-2)/5)*7)+INT((ROWS($C$1:C2)-2)/20)*8
```

The first part alone would be `=1+(INT((ROWS($C$1:C2)-2)/5)*7)` and the added part takes care of the changes at the 5th change.

Hopefully, that will suit your needs better!

Addendum:

Couple of notes regarding the formula:

```
INT((ROWS($C$1:C2)-2)/5)*7
                      ^  ^
                      a  b
```

`a` gives the frequency when 'change' of `b` has to be applied. So in the above, 7 will be added after 5 rows, and extending the logic to the other part of the final formula, 8 is being added on top of the first 7 (total 15) added every 20 rows (i.e. after 4 changes each of 5 rows).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for boils down to adding another 8 every 20th row. This can be achieved by adding `FLOOR((ROW()-2)/20;1)*8` to your formula.